# laravel app.js after install vuetify large file size

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, filesize

I try to add **vuetify** in **laravel** and make web admin. but my `app.js` file is over **6mb 7mb**.

```
Using laravel 5.8 and vuetify
```

how can to reduce file size?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are using minified version of vuetify.

run following command

```
npm install vuetify vuetify-loader stylus stylus-loader style-loader css-loader --save
```

Follow the reference here: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-reduce-your-vue-js-bundle-size-with-webpack-3145bf5019b7

Answer (score 0):

Use [A-la-carte](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte) to only import modules you really need.